# WCF dual end points

Tags: wcf

I am working on a WCF service with JSON behaviour which I want to expose both as REST and as SOAP.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITicket
{
    [WebGet]
    [OperationContract]
    Ticket[] GetAllTickets();

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{value}")]
    [OperationContract]
    Ticket GetTicketById(int Id);

    //[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{value}")]
    [OperationContract]
    Ticket[] GetTickets(string Ids);

    [OperationContract ]
    void AddTicket(Ticket ticket);

    [OperationContract ]
    void UpdateTicket(int Id);
}
```

My config settings are:

```
<service name="WCF_Rest_SOAP_JSON_Service.TicketService"
         behaviorConfiguration="TicketServiceBehavior" >
   <endpoint 
       address="soap" 
       behaviorConfiguration="SOAPEndPointBehavior" 
       binding="basicHttpBinding" 
       contract="WCF_Rest_SOAP_JSON_Service.ITicket"/>
   <endpoint 
       address="rest" 
       behaviorConfiguration="RESTEndPointBehavior" 
       binding="webHttpBinding" 
       contract="WCF_Rest_SOAP_JSON_Service.ITicket"/>
</service>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TicketServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SOAPEndPointBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="RESTEndPointBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

What I did was:

1. Created a blank solution
2. Added WCF Service Application

Now my questions are:

When I run the service, I directly go to the IIS directly listing, after clicking my service, I get the following error:

> The endpoint at '`http://localhost:3505/TicketService.svc/soap`' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.**

I also ran the WCFTestClient.exe and after passing this url (`http://localhost:3505/TicketService.svc`), I got the following error:

> Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

Any ideas how can I resolve these 1 and 2 (I tried different solutions from stack overflow but unsuccessful so far.

Comment: For the 1st error, you need to remove `<webHttp />` from the SOAP endpoint behavior and replace it with something more suitable, like `<basicHttp />`

Comment: @Alex Can't find any option compatible or starting with <basicHttp />, can you please elaborate further?

Comment: Sorry, my bad then. If you simply remove the `<webHttp />` from the SoapEndpoint, does it work?

Comment: @Alex I commented out all the methods in the interface except the first method, removed <webHttp /> and it worked but have 2 more problems now
1. If I uncomment the second method and try to run  my service, it says this error "Operation 'GetTicketById' in contract 'ITicket' has a UriTemplate that expects a parameter named 'VALUE', but there is no input parameter with that name on the operation."
2. While running the first method, how can I get to know that I am using the service as SOAP or REST?

Comment: Edit:
@AlexBarac
Now I am able to run the second method as well, but the second problem is still there i.e. do not know if I am testing these methods as REST or SOAP?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience using REST services. I can help you only with the SOAP ones...